# Why a regular expression `[A-z]` is considered suspicious

Tags: regex

I'm using PHPStorm with PHP Inspections. To validate a given value is in Base64 format I'm testing against the regular expression

```
^[A-z0-9/\+]+=*$
```

PHP Inspections mentions

```
'A-z' range in '[A-z0-9/\+]' is looking rather suspicious, please check.
```

I know A range of `A-z` means from character with code #65 to character with code #122. There is no other character than standard-latin characters in that range.

So I can't see anything suspicious with this regular expression. The only thing maybe, if there's any charset I don't know with any non-standard-latin characters in that mentioned range.

Comment: It's a common typo, you can always turn off such inspection.

Comment: @emix I know I can, but I don't decide to until I know why it occurres.